# null object after JSON data request

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am writing a code where I request JSON Object from url using Volley library. In my MainActivity I need to use this JSON Object so I need to wait for the response to be ready before going on with the code. For that, I implemented an interface with a method ProcessFinished that I define in my MainActivity and an AppController. Even with that, I still have an error when trying to call the requested Object in my Main Activity. Here's an extract of the used code :

```
public class GetData{

    public String loadAllData(final DataAsyncResponse callBack){
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return mydata;}


public interface DataAsyncResponse {

    void processFinished(String mydata);

}
```

In my ActivityMain :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = new GetData().loadAllData(new DataAsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinished(String mydata) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value for `data` within the `processFinished()` callback. The way you're setting it now won't work because the value isn't ready yet at that point. Although it's hard to tell because you haven't included all the code, something like this should work:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new GetData().loadAllData(new DataAsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinished(String mydata) {
            data = myData;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This won't work either because I'll be able to use data only inside processFinished method. I need to use data in many parts of my MainActivity code. Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: You've just discovered the difficulty of asynchronous programming. Whatever you do with `data`, you need to do it in `processFinished()`. That's just how it works. You can set `data` to be a global variable that accessible from anywhere in `MainActivity`, but then you have to decide how you'll deal with it when it's null (as in, before `processFinished()` is called).